# iOS Core data NSCocoaErrorDomain 134020

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using persistent container to load data to tableviewcontroller, but everytime I want to save the data, it show me strange error like this.

The error occur everytime I access the Friend list page after load other VC (from tabbar).
If I open directly to Friend list page, no error occur.

Notes*: I have container initialization in every ViewController that has access to Core data.

Can you help me?

```
An error occurred while saving: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134020 "(null)" UserInfo={NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey=<Friend: 0x6080008954a0> (entity: Friend; id: 0x608000a33340 <x-coredata:///Friend/t78E3F129-DFFC-46DC-B542-7B2378382AB587> ; data: {
    accepted = 1;
    canAccept = 0;
    name = "Foo Bar";
    profilePicture = nil;
    username = foobar;
}),
NSUnderlyingException=Store <NSSQLCore: 0x600000375840> (URL: file:///Users/foobar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/69C6FA49-8B83-4289-AA3B-90D8FE065492/data/Containers/Data/Application/27388AC0-B1C6-4D25-8194-3DCA8AF4818C/Library/Application%20Support/Renungan.sqlite) cannot hold instances of entity (<NSEntityDescription: 0x60800035c510>) name Friend, managedObjectClassName Friend, renamingIdentifier Friend, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {
accepted = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6080006e9080>), name accepted, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Friend, renamingIdentifier accepted, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 800 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue (null)";
canAccept = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6080006e9100>), name canAccept, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Friend, renamingIdentifier canAccept, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 800 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue (null)";
name = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6080006e9180>), name name, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Friend, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
profilePicture = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6080006e9200>), name profilePicture, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Friend, renamingIdentifier profilePicture, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
username = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6080006e9280>), name username, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Friend, renamingIdentifier username, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
}, subentities {
}, userInfo {
}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (
)}
```

Here is my container initialization

```
container.loadPersistentStores { (_, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to Load Persistent Store")
                print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")

            } else {
                self.setupView()

                do {
                    let acceptedPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "accepted = %@", NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true))
                    self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = acceptedPredicate
                    try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
                } catch {
                    let fetchError = error as NSError
                    print("Unable to Perform Fetch Request")
                    print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
                }

                self.updateView()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you already suspect the cause of the problem.  You can't create multiple  persistent containers pointing to the same file and expect it to work.  All of the different containers will all be trying to write to the file at the same time and will mess each other up.  Create a single   persistent container for the entire application and only use that.  Also delete your app before running them again to remove the corrupted files.

Comment: where should I create the single persistent container @jon-rose ??
I've create the container in every single viewcontroller that has function to access core data now.

In every controller I make, I declare it on the top ```private let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Renungan")```

Comment: Either the appDelegate or a sharedSingleton.

Comment: like this ```private let container = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer``` ??

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error in XCTest unit tests, Xcode 9.4.1, Swift 4.1.

To fix it, inspired by [@Jon Rose' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44653194/1107226), I declared my Core Data stack class as a static variable, so all tests would be using the same instance. (The stack class is not a singleton; probably should be!)

For example, in the stack class I have a method to drop all data, so I can start with a clean slate...

```
// let stackClass = StackClass()      // gives me basically the same error as OP
static let stackClass = StackClass()  // works fine
...
func testSomething {
    TestClass.stackClass.dropAllData
    // rest of test code
}
```

***Update:*** I just changed the stack class to a singleton, replaced the unit test instance with the shared instance, and all worked great as well!

stack class:

```
static let shared = StackClass()
private init() {
    // initialization code here; called only once, upon 1st 'shared' instantiation
}
```

test class:

```
func testSomething {
    StackClass.shared.dropAllData
    // rest of test code
}
```